# Column filter values

Tags: custom, filter, column-data

When you view a list/library in SharePoint you have the ability to filter on a selected column. For instance, you have a column called "Food" and you may want to filter the results based on a value under "Food".

I understand that the filter values will always show a list of unique values for that column. Is this something that can be modified? For instance, grouping the "Food" values by "Food Type". It would essentially be the user clicking the column header and a bunch of "Food Types" appear. They would select a "Food Type" and a fly-out would appear with all the related "Food Types". Can something be modified to achieve this or am I pipe dreaming?